# WFC Service Not Seeing Operation Contract

Tags: c#, wcf

I am having a weird problem where I have a wcf service that has some Operation Contracts but when I add the service reference to another project they are there.

When I go to add -> add service reference. I put in the wfc url and the service shows up.

When I look at the operations list I see those endpoints but when I hit "ok" and then I try to find those endpoints in my project they are not found.

How can I go about debugging this?

Comment: Hard to say, it should like there is an issue with your versioning.  Instead of adding a service reference.  Try doing things manually and Import the service contract that way you should see the methods there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct Data Anotations on your interface, for example:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(ExceptionMessage))]
        List<student> GetStudents();

        [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(ExceptionMessage))]
        void AddStudents(Student student);

        [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(ExceptionMessage))]
        void DeleteStudent(long StudentId); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have a [Service Contract] interface. And it should contain your methods

Answer (score 0):

When you successfully add the service reference, the proxy class will be automatically generated in the project:

[image]

And it will automatically generate web.config, web.config contains endpoint information:

[image]